# preselect checkbox and spinner on android

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-checkbox

I'm trying to get the xml to display a checkbox and spinner as preselected or otherwise based on a variable I have from the database (i.e. whether user has already chosen the option for the checkbox, or a selection on spinner already chosen by user)

the xml code for the checkbox and spinner is as follows

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/che"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="itemClicked"        />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/tmrs"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"      />
```

The code on the java side is

```
public class Optio extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.optio);
        tqo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.toq);

        ArrayAdapter adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource 
                (this, R.array.mpm, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        tqo.setAdapter(adapter);
        tqo.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);        
    }


    ///my own code below, no errors but doesn't work
    public void tree(View v) {
        boolean isChecked = true;
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.unrt);
        cb.setChecked(isChecked);       
    }
}
```

As you can see, i'm a newbie with android, so you may have to spell it out for me.. I appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you mean its not within onCreate {}? I will try it later. Thanks in advance for the tip.

Comment: You are right, it works! I feel a bit like an idiot. Thanks

Comment: Btw, do you know how it works for the spinner?

Comment: I have made bigger mistakes than that, so no worries :) You can set the spinner item by using `Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_id); spinner.setSelection(int selectionPosition);`

Comment: Thanks a lot. 2 simple comments from you saved me from probably hours of pointless head scratching. ;)